# How to call the callback method in C# for socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I would like to know whether it is possible to call the callback method or not? I am creating a project which is connecting with socket and receiving and sending data for 24hrs. Here I am using BeginReceive() and EndReceive() method.

Below is my code:

```
public void Receive(Socket client)
{
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = client;

    try
    {
        if (m_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            Connect();
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        logstr = se.Message;
        write_log(logstr, "Receive", "Receive");
    }
}

public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket client = state.workSocket;
    string receiveData = "";
    string sendData = "";
    int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        state.sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);

        receiveData = state.sb.ToString();

        this.IsBulk.Items.Insert(0, receiveData);
        sendData = getReply(receiveData);
        write_log(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + receiveData, "bytesRead", "bytesRead");

        try
        {
            Object objData = sendData;
            byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());

            if (m_clientSocket != null)
            {
                m_clientSocket.Send(byData);
            }

            write_log(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + sendData, "sendData", "sendData");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            logstr = se.Message;
            write_log(logstr, "WaitForData", "waitfordata");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        receiveData = state.sb.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(receiveData))
        {
            write_log(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + receiveData, "receiveData2", "receiveData2");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I am debugging line by line then my cursor is not going to the callback method ReceiveCallback(). So, I am confused whether it is ok or I am doing some mistake? If I am doing some mistake then I would like to know how can I call the ReceiveCallback() method from another function. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Maybe it's just a debugging issue due to a seperate thread beeing started. Do you get your entries in the log?

Comment: No I don't get any error logs for this. So, do you mean that ReceiveCallBack() method will be called automatically. I don't need to call that? Actually I am so new in socket so I would appreciate your help on this. Thank you

Comment: As far as I understand it you must execute an EndReceive after using BeginReceive to "finish" the receiving process. Usually I do that different, I do not use those Begin and EndReceive methods and also don't use the socket directly. I usually use TcpClient, access the NetworkStream and read from it in an seperate thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would really appreciate if you can give me some example on that. Thank you

Comment: I've posted a little example, I hope it helps you a little bit. It is not best practice of course but one of many ways to go...

Comment: @ Markus thanks a lot...the example is wonderful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've asked for it, here are 2 little examples, one for the TcpClient and one for the TcpServer.

A little TcpServer example:

```
namespace TcpServer
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains possible exit codes for the application.
    /// </summary>
    public enum ApplicationExitCode
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents an exit code which hint's that there was an abnormal program termination.
        /// </summary>
        Error = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents an exit code which hint's that there was no abnormal program termination.
        /// </summary>
        OK = 0
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents out Program class.
    /// </summary>
    public class Server
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the port on which the server will try to listen.
        /// </summary>
        private const int SERVERPORT = 12345;

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the threads that handle the client connections.
        /// </summary>
        private static List<Thread> clientThreads = new List<Thread>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The entry point of our application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The command line arguments.</param>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Establish a tcpListener on any network interface at port SERVERPORT
            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, SERVERPORT);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localEndpoint);

            try
            {
                // Try to start the listener which will try to bind to the socket.
                listener.Start();
            }
            catch (SocketException socketEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server: Unable to establish listener at {0}:{1}", localEndpoint.Address.ToString(), localEndpoint.Port.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(socketEx.Message);
                Environment.Exit((int)ApplicationExitCode.Error);
            }

            // Print status information.
            Console.WriteLine("Server: You can terminate the application by pressing the ESC-key.");
            Console.WriteLine("Server: Listener at {0}:{1} established, waiting for incomming connections...", localEndpoint.Address.ToString(), localEndpoint.Port.ToString());

            bool listenForClients = true; // Used for controlling the listener loop.
            int connectionID = 0; // Used for distinguishing the connections in the console output.

            do
            {
                // Check for user input.
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    listenForClients = Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape;
                }

                // Check for new client.
                if (listener.Pending())
                {
                    // Create a new thread for the connecting client.
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ClientWorker));

                    // Set the thread as background thread (which would/could terminate with the main thread - we don't want that).
                    t.IsBackground = true;

                    // Set the thread name to the connectionID (which is a number increasing with each new client).
                    t.Name = (connectionID++).ToString();

                    // Start the thread and pass a reference to the new client object which we receive from AcceptTcpClient().
                    t.Start((object)listener.AcceptTcpClient());

                    // Add the thread to the list so we can terminate it later.
                    clientThreads.Add(t);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Sleep - I like that ;-)
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
            while (listenForClients);

            // Stop the listener.
            listener.Stop();

            // Print status message.
            Console.WriteLine("Server: Sending abort request to all threads.");

            // Send abort request to all client threads.
            foreach (Thread t in clientThreads)
            {
                t.Abort();
            }

            // Print status message.
            Console.WriteLine("Server: Waiting for all threads to terminate.");

            // Wait for all client threads to really terminate.
            foreach (Thread t in clientThreads)
            {
                t.Join();
            }

            // Print status message.
            Console.WriteLine("Server: Exiting application.");

            // Exit the application.
            Environment.Exit((int)ApplicationExitCode.OK);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the client thread which is started for each new connection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The tcpClient object.</param>
        private static void ClientWorker(object data)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)data;
            NetworkStream ns;
            string threadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
            bool processData = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Started.", threadName);

            // Try to fetch the network stream
            try
            {
                ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Unable to fetch the network stream, exiting thread.", threadName);
                return;
            }

            // Print cool message.
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Network stream fetched.", threadName);

            try
            {
                byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
                byte[] sendBuffer;
                int bytesRead = 0;
                string message;

                while (processData)
                {
                    // If data is available on the stream
                    if (ns.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        // Read data from the stream.
                        bytesRead = ns.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length);

                        // Write the received number of bytes.
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Received {1} bytes.", threadName, bytesRead);

                        // Write the bytes (in hex format).
                        Console.Write("Thread {0}: ", threadName);

                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0:X2} ", receiveBuffer[i]);
                        }

                        // "Decode" the data.
                        message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThread {0}: Decoding data using ASCII table.", threadName);

                        // Write the decoded message.
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: {1}", threadName, message);

                        // Build the answer byte array.
                        sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hab's bekommen ;-)\r\n");

                        // Write the answer.
                        ns.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                // Print status message.
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Abort requested.", threadName);

                // Set loop condition.
                processData = false;

                // Reset abort request.
                Thread.ResetAbort();
            }
            catch (Exception generalEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Exception occured.", threadName);
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: {1}", threadName, generalEx.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // If the network stream still exists.
                if (ns != null)
                {
                    // Flush the stream.
                    ns.Flush();

                    // Close the stream.
                    ns.Close();

                    // Dispose the stream.
                    ns.Dispose();
                }

                // If the tcpClient object still exists.
                if (tcpClient != null)
                {
                    // Close the client.
                    tcpClient.Close();
                }

                // Print status message.
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Stopping.", threadName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A little TcpClient example:

```
namespace TcpClient
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents our Server class.
    /// </summary>
    public class Client
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The entry point of our application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The command line arguments.</param>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress;
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
            TcpClient tcpClient;
            NetworkStream ns = null;
            int port;

            // Let the user input the IP-Address.
            Console.Write("Bitte geben Sie die IPAdresse an: ");
            ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // Let the user input the port number.
            Console.Write("Bitte geben Sie den Port an: ");
            port = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // Create a new IPEndPoint object.
            ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a new TcpClient object.
            tcpClient = new TcpClient();

            // Connect the client to the endpoint.
            tcpClient.Connect(ipEndPoint);

            // Try to fetch the network stream
            try
            {
                ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to fetch the network stream, exiting thread.");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            // Print cool message.
            Console.WriteLine("Network stream fetched.");

            // Declare receive and send buffer and some other stuff.
            byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendBuffer;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            string message;
            bool processData = true;

            // Until someone types "exit"
            while (processData)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter your message: ");

                message = Console.ReadLine();

                if (message.ToLower() == "exit")
                {
                    processData = false;
                    continue;
                }

                // Get bytes of the message.
                sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Write the data into the stream.
                ns.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);

                // Read data from the stream.
                bytesRead = ns.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length);

                // Decode the data.
                message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // Write it into the console window.
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }

            ns.Flush();
            ns.Close();
            ns.Dispose();
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you somehow ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice and helpful answer.But I have a question. My program is like 24hrs running as it is connecting to some Telecommunication company. So, I would like to know if I flush the networkStream will it affect my live connection? Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correclty. Do you mean that if you execute a "flush" you think your connection could break (=be disconnected)?
Anyway: I would not suggest holding a connection open "forever" and if you need a permanent connection I would suggest implementing some kind of alive message exchange. Example: Send an alive message every 10 seconds and expect to catch an alive message at least every 30 seconds. With this and an intelligent state machine you can handle disconnectes very easy. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Thank you so much you really helped me a lot. your example is really good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Socket.BeginReceive()` method, you only *define* what is the callback which will be called when data is sent to the socket.

So if you are going line-by-line in `Receive()`, it is normal that you don't jump to the `ReceiveCallback()` method.

However, if you also put a breakpoint in `ReceiveCallback()`, and start sending data to your socket, you will see it get called as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. OK I will try that and let you know.

Comment: If it works I'm wondering why you won't get entries in your log - meaning why `write_log` isn't executed.

Comment: @yorah Thank you so much for your explanation. Yes my cursor is now going there but after taking a long time. But now I can understand that when it's receiving something from the remote server then only it is happening. Thank a lot.